# What are the reasons or concerns with using an LED power supply to power a motor?

Tags: power-supply, motor, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-motor, led-driver

What are the reasons or concerns with using an LED power supply to power a motor?

If the motor is controlled via PWM and can be soft started would this alleviate the concerns / make it work reliably?

Comment: What LED power supply? What motor?

Comment: Assuming the supply is constant voltage and of sufficient capacity for the load I don't think there would be any concerns.

Comment: It really depends on what does it mean for the LED supply to specify itself as a LED supply. We can't know why the manufacturer did that and how it differs from any other supply unless you provide information about this LED supply you have.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I was thinking about using the MEAN WELL HLG-240H-24 but after looking at the answer from vir it seems that the constant current call out in the datasheet would cause issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that a motor is an inductive load.

In particular, this means that when your PWM is "off", the current will try to keep flowing in the motor: if it has nowhere to go, voltage will go up until something breaks. Depending on the LED driver, it might provide a "hidden" path to evacuate this current, or not, depending on the technology. In a motor driver, you normally have freewheeling diodes to provide a path for this current (sometimes its just the body diodes of the mosfets).

If you plan to use a LED driver, I strongly recommend you place a diode in parallel with the motor (in the "blocking" direction).

Another thing the LED driver might not like, is if the motors works as a generator. As long as you don't turn the motor by hand, a don't slow brutally, you should be fine.

Finally, the inductive load itself might influence the stability of the feedback of the voltage/current regulator of your LED driver: in this case, you might run into problems.

So if you have the LED driver at hand, and don't care much about destroying it, then just give it a try, with a diode in parallel to the motor, and avoid big accelerations/deceleration.

If you need reliability, or if you don't want to take any risk for your equipment, then just buy a dedicated motor driver.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have one that is constant voltage instead of constant current and you should be fine.  At my company we run all kinds of things off of LED power supplies since they're quite a bit more rugged than the standard desktop power brick.  You *might* run into issues with the starting current surge (~3x the running current depending on the motor) tripping some internal overcurrent protection, but you'd need to look at the datasheet for the specific power supply you have in mind to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking about using the MEAN WELL HLG-240H-24

That's a dual constant current and constant voltage supply meaning that it puts out 24v in constant voltage mode until the load reaches 10A, then it lowers the voltage as it drops into constant current mode.

If you were sure your load was less than 10 A you could use it, although it would be a very expensive choice since you don't need the constant current feature.

Comment: I Was planning on this power supply supplying power to the controller that controls the motor.  If I was planning to use the overcurrent protection as a means of turning off power to the whole system if the motor were to hit a hard stop then there might be an issue? But maybe if the motor goes into a hard stop and the voltage drops for the controller and motor driving electronics then the current gets cut off from  motor even if the power supply is trying to keep the current constant?